# Flask-Admin remove "Home" button

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

How do I remove the "Home" button in Python's Flask-Admin library?

[image]

```
from flask_admin import Admin

flask_admin = Admin(app, 
    name='Customer Admin', 
    template_mode='bootstrap3', 
    # endpoint refers to the blueprint [e.g. url_for('admin_cust.index')] where index() is the function/view
    index_view=SecuredAdminIndexView(url='/admin_cust', endpoint='admin_cust')
)

# Add model (database table) views to the page
flask_admin_cust.add_view(UserView(User, db.session, category='Users', name='View/Edit User', endpoint='users'))
flask_admin.add_view(CustSubGroupView(CustSubGroup, db.session, name='Groups', endpoint='groups'))
flask_admin.add_view(GwView(Gw, db.session, endpoint='units', name='Units'))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flask-Admin `BaseView` has a method `is_visible(self)`, the [source code](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/base.py#L326) has a note:

*Please note that item should be both visible and accessible to be displayed in menu.*

For example, an index view could be along the following lines:

```
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin import AdminIndexView
from flask_admin import expose, AdminIndexView


class DashboardView(AdminIndexView):

    def is_visible(self):
        # This view won't appear in the menu structure
        return False

    @expose('/')
    def index(self):

        return self.render(
            'admin/dashboard.html',
        )

flask_admin = Admin(app,
    name='Customer Admin',
    template_mode='bootstrap3',
    index_view=DashboardView()
)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to create a totally new nav-bar. I just want to remove one button.

Comment: That's what the answer achieves. Removing the NavBar is referring to another answer on SO.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't remove the brand button/link though. Whether I delete the <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ admin_view.admin.url }}">{{ admin_view.admin.name }}</a> in the base.html template, or create a whole new no-brand-layout.html, exactly as you described, the brand button/link is still there, amazingly! I know... shocking... :(

Comment: I'll run through the debugger in the morning.

Comment: you did it! The "is_visible(self)" method was all I needed! Thanks soooooo much!!!  :D

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way of at least changing the name from the default "Home".

My new name is 'NOT HOME' in the code below. This is a start...

```
flask_admin = Admin(app, 
    name='Customer Admin', 
    template_mode='bootstrap3', 
    # endpoint refers to the blueprint [e.g. url_for('admin_cust.index')] where index() is the function/view
    index_view=SecuredAdminIndexView(name='NOT HOME', url='/admin_cust', endpoint='admin_cust')
)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a little hacky but very simple; just add the line:

```
flask_admin._menu = flask_admin._menu[1:]
```

This will just remove the first item, which is the home button. The problem I had with the other solutions is that it doesn't only remove the home button but also the home view. This solution only removes the home buttom.

Comment: Not working on latest version. :(